# Jquery md-timepicker is not working in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Here is my Html code

```
    <tr ng-repeat="BreakData in $root.dataFromController[$root.selectedShift].BreakData">
        <td style="font-size:20px; text-align:left;">{{BreakData.BreakName}}</td>
        <td>
<md-input-container class="hmSchIn" ng-hide="TblRowData.strScheduleCompressorNameShiftStartTime == ''">
            <input type="text" id="timepicker" ng-model="BreakData.StartTime" ng-readonly="true" />
    </md-input-container>
         </td>
```

[image: Here is the output screen]

Only the first input field is opening but rest are not working.

Comment: Probably because you're reusing that ID for multiple elements in the page.

Comment: Even I think so. But what to do to solve this problem?

Comment: Actually I’m not sure you are initializing the input correctly. Can you link the docs of the version you are using for the timepicker?

Comment: Not sure of the version, but if you need to diversify your id’s you can use $index to assist you.  id=“timepicker{{$index}}”

Comment: Thanks a lot. It started working by writing id=“timepicker{{$index}}.

Answer (score 0):

You have ng-readonly set to true. Either delete that attribute or set it to false.

```
<input type="text" id="timepicker" ng-model="BreakData.StartTime" ng-readonly="false" />
```